# How do I keep the Woocommerce terms and conditions information open?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently when setting terms and conditions for users to agree to in Woocomerce, the terms and conditions are not displayed until the user clicks on the terms and conditions link in the checkbox text.

Is there a way to have the terms and conditions always open by default? The terms and conditions for my current project are short, but vitally important before a user makes their purchase.

Comment: Legally speaking; they do not have to be open. Just easily accessible. Open or closed by default; most users will not read them. Those that will want to read will open it themselves. Don't create un-wanted disturbances on your website.

Comment: I generally agree with this, however it is a requirement from my client. People are booking non-refundable event tickets for an event on a small island. We need them to understand that if they haven't booked their flights and accommodation first, they will be swimming to the event and sleeping on the beach.

Answer (score 0):

There is JavaScript code that closes the T&C box. 
It is usually located in `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js` (actually `checkout.min.js`)

That's as close as I have time to get to it right now. If you know JS, you'll get it. ;-)